How to pass a table data (which is in SQLite) to Svelte page through Flask
I use command to create a svelte project named "table-test". Commands: npm create svelete@latest then npm install.
The initial page works fine. I add a "table" folder under router then add three files (+page.svelte, Table.svelte and data-store.js). This page works fine. +page.svelte import the data from data-store.js file then pass to the Table.svelte and display on the page. Now I create a server.py in "table-test" and open SQLite database file then read a table from it. My question is how to pass those data to the page of table?
The +page.svelte under "table" folder:
<script>
    import Table from './Table.svelte';
    import { studentsArray, colors } from './data-store.js';
    
    let redStyle = "redTable";
    let blueStyle = "blueTable";
</script>

<Table tableData={$studentsArray} style={redStyle}/>
<Table tableData={$colors} style={blueStyle}/>

The Table.svelte under "table" folder:
<script>
    export let tableData;
    export let style;
</script>

<table class={style}>
    <!-- <thead>
        <tr>
            {#each Object.keys(tableData[0]) as columnHeading}
                <th>{columnHeading}</th>
            {/each}
        <tr/>
    </thead> -->
    <tbody>
        {#each Object.values(tableData) as row}
            <tr>
                {#each Object.values(row) as cell}
                    <td>{cell}</td>
                {/each}
            </tr>
        {/each}
    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    table.redTable {
        border: 2px solid #A40808;
        background-color: #EEE7DB;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.redTable td, table.redTable th {
        border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
        padding: 3px 2px;
    }
    table.redTable tbody td {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    table.redTable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #F5C8BF;
    }
    table.redTable thead {
        background: #A40808;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bb4646 0%, #ad2020 66%, #A40808 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bb4646 0%, #ad2020 66%, #A40808 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bb4646 0%, #ad2020 66%, #A40808 100%);
    }
    table.redTable thead th {
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #A40808;
    }
    table.redTable thead th:first-child {
        border-left: none;
    }

        table.blueTable {
        border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
        border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
        padding: 3px 2px;
    }
    table.blueTable tbody td {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #D0E4F5;
    }
    table.blueTable thead {
        background: #1C6EA4;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
        border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
    }
    table.blueTable thead th {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
    }
    table.blueTable thead th:first-child {
        border-left: none;
    }
</style>

The data-store.js under "table" folder:
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    
export let studentsArray = writable([
    {
        "Name" : "Maria",
        "Favorite Subject" : "Math",
        "Age" : 14
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Jose",
        "Favorite Subject" : "Science",
        "Age" : 13
    }
]);

export let colors = writable([
    {
        "Name" : "Cyan",
        "HEX" : "#00FFFF"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Yellow",
        "HEX" : "#FFFF00"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Blue",
        "HEX" : "#0000FF"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Lime",
        "HEX" : "#00FF00"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Red",
        "HEX" : "#FF0000"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "White",
        "HEX" : "#FFFFFF"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Black",
        "HEX" : "#000000"
    },
])

The table in SQLite:[('Owner', 'This company'), ('User', 'Shopping mall'), ('Client', 'Male adult')]
server.py code:
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import sqlite3

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

# Path for our main Svelte page
@app.route("/")
def base():
    return send_from_directory('/src/routes/table', '+page.svelte')

# Path for all the static files (compiled JS/CSS, etc.)
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def home(path):
    return send_from_directory('/', path)

@app.route("/table")
def show_table():
    database = sqlite3.connect("Toilet.db")
    databasecur = database.cursor()
    selectedtable = 1140
    table_name = "table_" + str(selectedtable)
    sql_check = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name
    databasecur.execute(sql_check)
    check_result = databasecur.fetchall()
    database.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


In the +page.js/ts file, use a load function to fetch the data from the respective endpoint. It will be be passed to the data property of the page (see the linked docs).
(Serving a single +page.svelte source file from the python server seems pretty pointless, you probably would want to either have a standalone SvelteKit application (with a separate Python-powered API service) or use the static adapter to compile it down to just static front-end components that can be served as part of the Python backend.)

Thank you very much for the information. Actually, I have learnt svelte only one month. I'm planning to build a website which has 117 main pages. More than 100 pages are displaying a table. User can type in content in the table which will be saved in SQLite database file. Those contents will be loaded up on the page when user opens this page next time. Anyway, I will follow your advise and keep learning about adapter. Thanks again.

To be able to query the database more easily, I recommend using Flask-SQLAlchemy. The database schema would then look something like this.
class User(db.Model):
    id:Mapped[int] = db.mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    desc:Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)

To be able to serialize the requested data more easily to JSON, it makes sense to use Flask-Marshmallow and Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy. A schema is automatically created in accordance with the database schema.
class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User

The endpoint for delivering the data in JSON format would then be as follows.
@app.route('/data')
def data():
    users = db.session.execute(db.select(User)).scalars()
    users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
    return users_schema.jsonify(users)

Instead of serving the file +page.svelte, you should, as @brunnerh mentioned, serve the file index.html of the built frontend. A separate endpoint is required for this. All other files can be delivered by removing the path prefix for the folder static when instantiating the Flask application. This is done by assigning an empty string to the attribute static_url_path.
app = Flask(__name__, 
    static_url_path=''
)

# ...

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

It is then advisable to create a proxy configuration in the frontend's vite.config.js file, which passes the requests directly to the backend.
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/data': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
        }
    },
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
});

In order to be able to deliver the frontend via Flask, it is necessary to install an adapter. In this case, the "adapter-static", which is configured in the svelte.config.js file. After the npm run build command is executed, the result is then created in the static folder of the Flask application.
// import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        // adapter: adapter()
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: '../backend/src/static',
            assets: '../backend/src/static',
            fallback: false,         // -> +page.js: export const prerender = true;
            precompress: false
        }),
    }
};

export default config;

The actual query of the data takes place, as @brunnerh already mentioned, in the load() function, which is located in the +page.js file. The data is then passed on to the variable to be defined in the script part of the +page.svelte file.
export const prerender = true;
export const ssr = false;

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ params, fetch }) {
    const users = await fetch('/data')
        .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.json());
    return { users };
}


You can find the complete example here.

Thank you so much for the code. I'll spend more time on learning. A few hours ago, I figured out the code in index.html.

 {% for item in tableitem %}
  
{{item[0]}}
{{item[1]}}
{{item[2]}}
{{item[3]}}

 {% endfor %}
I'll try to merge this file with other frontend files. Thanks again.
